# Configure VR support that enables to "look" around and receive user input (Google Cardboard button)

Tags: unity, android, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

When the user moves the head this means that the phone in the HMD also moves and there are sensors that can detect the direction of the phone so that the image can update correctly. Also to note that the HMD has a button that can be clicked and trigger an action.

In early 2019, in order to implement both of the above mentioned functionalities (look around and click), stared by configuring Settings > Player > XR Settings and add Cardboard as Virtual Reality SDK. Then, I've used the prefab [GVR Editor Emulator](https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/unity/prefab/GvrEditorEmulator). It was basically going to [this link](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/download), download Google VR SDK for Unity, drag it into Unity and import.

Once the import finished, it's possible to see in Assets a folder named Google VR. The prefab can be found then under Assets > Google VR > Prefabs > GvrEditorEmulator, copy and paste in our scene.

Now, more than 1 year after, when I go to the GvrEditorEmulator page, can see

[image]

> November 6, 2019 update:
>
> - There's a new open source Cardboard SDK that offers a streamlined API, improved device compatibility, and built-in viewer profile QR
>   code scanning. We recommend that all developers actively building for
>   Google Cardboard migrate to the new Cardboard SDK: iOS, Android NDK,
>   Unity XR Plugin (SDK)

What changes in the process considering this update?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here. Are you looking for advice about whether you should use the newer Cardboard SDK rather than the older Google VR SDK? If so, that's a "which technology to use" question that we do not handle here. Have you run into any particular obstacle making the SDK of your choice work for your needs? If so, please edit your question to give us more context on where you're stuck.

Comment: @DMGregory I know how the procedure worked before. What I don't know is if this prefab used is still supported by the new SDK and, if not, what is the substitute?

Comment: What happens if you try to use that prefab? Do you encounter an error we can help you solve?

Comment: @DMGregory didn't try to use it it yet (was wondering as the same need might arise in a near future) and couldn't spot anything in the documentation

Comment: Give it a try first so you know whether you have a problem. Then ask for help solving it once you know what the problem is.

Comment: @DMGregory asked here in this community because thought that someone who uses / might have used it will know about it (hence saving that testing time). Would that make it off-topic?